# AWS-CPP-SDK download from git fails

Tags: aws-sdk-cpp

I'd like to install the c++ sdk on my ec2 instance. The bash command to do this is given on this page: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-cpp/v1/developer-guide/setup.html

"To build the SDK from source"
...
"Clone with Git: git clone git@github.com:aws/aws-sdk-cpp.git"

I downloaded git on my instance and tried this command and get these errors:

"*The authenticity of host 'github.com (192.30.253.112)' can't be established.
RSA key fingerprint is SHA256:nThbg6kXUpJWGl7E1IGOCspRomTxdCARLviKw6E5SY8.
RSA key fingerprint is MD5:16:27:ac:a5:76:28:2d:36:63:1b:56:4d:eb:df:a6:48. 
Warning: Permanently added 'github.com,192.30.253.112' (RSA) to the list of known hosts.
Permission denied (publickey).
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.
Please make sure you have the correct access rights and the repository exists.*"

If I can't resolve this, then I need to do a direct download. Can I do a Direct download via curl? I'd like to be able to get a fresh download every time I launch a new instance so that I pick up all the new code updates.

Answer (score 2):

The given download(checkout)instruction is based on the assumption that you are using ssh to access Github. You should set up ssh key on Github to make that work.

Otherwise, you can use Https to check it out: git clone https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-cpp.git

Comment: Thank you for your feedback. That is what I ended up doing....Sorry, I don't have enough credit to give you an upvote.